# Type definition error in ResponseEntity Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

I have 2 microservices: gateway and another, which are connect with Feign.

When i do request directly to my microservice i have normal response. But if i do it with gateway i have exception:

```
Type definition error: [simple type, class FieldsDTO]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `FieldsDTO` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

This is my DTO class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class FieldsDTO {
    private Set<String> fieldNames;
    private List<ShortFiledsDTO> dataList;
}
```

Are there some thoughts how to fix it?

UPD:
ANSWER:

Definitely, you must to create default constructor, but i forgot to update model's version

Comment: can you add the code how the Gateway service tries to access the microservice?

Comment: Similar error and solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61458753/2987755

Comment: i did all the same, but it doesn't work

Comment: @dkb i have same annotations on DTOs

Comment: Why do you have a reference to ResponseEntity in the title of the question? It does not appear elsewhere in the code. I have the same problem, but it's generated by code I have no direct control over (spring-boot/feign/jackson)